Prevent an infinite loop while dispatching JavaScript events calling each other
I have a JavaScript Stimulus "controller" (I don't believe the framework matters here) attached to three different nodes:
<div id="foo" data-controller="scanner"></div>
<div id="bar" data-controller="scanner"></div>
<div id="baz" data-controller="scanner"></div>

What I'm trying to accomplish seems like a simple task... not for me, as I don't have an in-depth understanding of events, at least without causing an infinite loop:

When method activate is called (directly or as an event listener) the method deactivate should be called on other controllers (that is, except itself). For example:  #foo->activate is called then #bar->deactivate and #baz->deactivate should run

In a similar way: #bar->deactivate is called then #foo->activate and #baz->activate should run.


It seems I can't because an infinite loop occurs as soon as I call activate:
document.addEventListener('activate', this.activate)
document.addEventListener('deactivate', this.deactivate)

export default class {
    element; // the HTML element

    dispatch(event) {
       this.element.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(event, { bubbles: true }));
    }

    activate(e) {
      // Also check for !e (calling this method directly)
      if (!e || e.target === this.element) {
        this.dispatch('deactivate'); 
        document.addEventListener('keyup', this.onKeyUp);
      }
    }

    deactivate(e) {
      // Also check for !e (calling this method directly)
      if (!e || e.target !== this.element) {
        document.removeEventListener('keyup', this.onKeyUp);
        this.dispatch('activate');
      }
    }
}

Any help in developing this logic is much appreciated.

When you bind event handlers that way, you lose the this context.

you dispatch deactivate on the activated controller, which dispatches activate on the deactivated (same) controller, which dispatches deactivated on the same controller

e.currentTarget can be useful here. doc here. It returns the element that is handling the event. If this is different than e.target, you can execute rest of the code. Try if it helps. Also you can always just store the initial element like  var currentActivatedElement and then check for it.
